# How can I run the programs in my startup folder only on certain days of the week?

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot

I have a few programs in my startup folder (in Windows 7) that I ONLY want to run on weekdays. (Preferably I only want to run those during office hours.) How can I do this?
Is there something simple that I can check in the shortcut settings or perhaps a simple (free) program in which you can put programs and have those programs only start up at certain days?

Comment: I would just configure a scheduled task to run a specific program Monday through Friday at a certain time.

Comment: @Ramhound:  What if I would set it up to run at say 6am every weekday, wouldn't it just run when I log on after that time? (like 8am or 10am) Or won't it run, since it's not 6am anymore?

Comment: You do understand that a `Scheduled Task` can be configured to run every single day at a certain time right?  You don't have to trigger it only when the user logs into the account.

Comment: @Ramhound I do understand that, yes... but I want to let it run as soon as I login. That was the intention of my question... hence my question. :-)

Comment: You never said on login you have the impression you wanted it to happen 5 days a week daily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you're not going to find an easy solution.  The startup folder is rather dumb, and has no configurability.

Your best bet is to modify the shortcuts in your startup folder to run an intermediary program that would determine whether or not to execute the application... or delete them all and switch to using scheduled tasks that run at logon.

Comment: thanks! I knew it wouldn't be that easy.. but I was wondering if there was something out there that would do it. I guess TaskScheduler would do, but then again, have something that would trigger TaskScheduler (see Simkill's elaboration) every time isn't that 'clean' either..

Answer (score 2):

Yeah you can use the Windows Task Scheduler. Just open start and type in Task Scheduler and hit enter.

On the right you will see the Action section. Click on Create Task...

After that its quit simple, just follow the steps fill in the blanks and save. Your done!

For more info: [How to schedule a task](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/schedule-a-task)

Example: [How to Create a Automated Task that Runs at a Set Time in Windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/12444-task-scheduler-create-new-task.html)

Video example: [Windows Task Scheduler](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jOiSLCcMVq0)

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on thecompwiz's answer, create your scheduled tasks to run on logon to kick off the items usually located in startp (you'll need to move them elsewhere or they will still run on weekends), then create two batch files using the information located here http://www.howtogeek.com/51236/how-to-create-modify-and-delete-scheduled-tasks-from-the-command-line/ and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370256/enable-schedule-task-using-a-batch-file to run at a set time on Friday night to disable your other tasks, then enable them again on Monday morning. Job done!

You should also create a trigger where your other tasks run when the enable task runs on a Monday otherwise they wont run on logon on Monday morning

Comment: Thanks Simkill for the elaboration. As for creating jobs like that.. What if I would set it up to run at say 6am every weekday, wouldn't it just run when I log on after that time? (like 8am or 10am) Or won't it run, since it's not 6am anymore?